# not able to run new codeNameOne project createdd by the IDE

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-10

I have created a new CodeNameOne Project with netbans 10.0 and i am not able to run it
Output :

> /home/autonome/NetBeansProjects/javaWorkSpace/CodenameOne7/build.xml:17: taskdef A class needed by class com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources cannot be found: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>    using the classloader AntClassLoader[/home/autonome/NetBeansProjects/javaWorkSpace/CodenameOne7/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar]

java -version

> openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-3ubuntu116.04ppa1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-3ubuntu116.04ppa1, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version

> javac 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this isn't the Java version used by NetBeans. Make sure that NetBeans itself is running on JDK 11 and that JDK 11 is set as the JDK in the project preferences.

Comment: Yes , JDK 11 is setted in netbeans project as the JDK

Comment: Are you using an old project or an old plugin? Make sure your plugin is 6.x and make sure the project is up to date